# Displaying a React component in another folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my folder structure:

`js/common/components/Chart.jsx`

`js/manager/components/ManagerContent.jsx`

I want to display `Chart.jsx` inside `ManagerContent.jsx`.  I've gotten the following syntax to work for jsx files inside the same folder as `ManagerContent.jsx`:

```
var ManagerContent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Chart.jsx />
```

How do I modify the above for my case?

Comment: `import Chart from './Chart.jsx';` Then use it as `<Chart />`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end you need to import `Chart` from `js/common/components/Chart.jsx`.
How you will do it – depends of your environment. For example you could use [Require.js](http://requirejs.org).